# Swift - Convolution with Accelerate Framework

Tags: swift, convolution

I'm trying to do 1D convolution with Accelerate framework.

I can make it work but it seems like something goes wrong after a few experiments.

Here is my code:

```
import Accelerate

var N = 10000
var M = 10
var convN = N + M - 1

var xf = [Float](count:N, repeatedValue:0.0)
var yf = [Float](count:M, repeatedValue:0.0)

for i in 0..<N {
    xf[i] = Float(i+1)
}
for i in 0..<M {
    yf[i] = Float(i+1)
}

var outputf = [Float](count:convN, repeatedValue:0.0)

// padding zero
xf = [Float](count:convN-N, repeatedValue:0.0) + xf

var ptr_xf = UnsafePointer<Float>(xf)
var ptr_yf = UnsafePointer<Float>(yf).advancedBy(yf.count-1)

vDSP_conv(ptr_xf, 1, ptr_yf, -1, &outputf, 1, vDSP_Length(convN), vDSP_Length(M))
print("[Float]: \(outputf)")
```

I compile and run it with different `N` and `M`.

Then I check the result with the result from python package `numpy`.

Sometime it looks great but sometime it just give me some weird result like:

(`N`=6, `M`=3)

`Correct: [1.0, 4.0, 10.0, 16.0, 22.0, 28.0, 27.0, 18.0]`

`Result I get: [1.0, 4.0, 10.0, 16.0, 22.0, 28.0, 2.23692e+08, 4.47384e+08]`

Do I miss anything here?
I can not figure out what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have something to do with your Swift Version ? I am using V 3.0.2 and the following code works well for me.

```
import Accelerate

var N = 6
var M = 3

var convN = N + M - 1

var xf = [Float](repeating:0.0, count:N)
var yf = [Float](repeating:0.0, count:M)

for i in 0..<N {
    xf[i] = Float(i+1)
}
for i in 0..<M {
    yf[i] = Float(i+1)
}

var outputf = [Float](repeating:0.0, count:convN)

// padding zero
xf = [Float](repeating:0.0, count:convN-N) + xf

var ptr_xf = UnsafePointer<Float>(xf)
var ptr_yf = UnsafePointer<Float>(yf).advanced(by: yf.count-1)


vDSP_conv(ptr_xf, 1, ptr_yf, -1, &outputf, 1, vDSP_Length(convN), vDSP_Length(M))

print("[Float]: \(outputf)") // [Float]: [1.0, 4.0, 10.0, 16.0, 22.0, 28.0, 27.0, 18.0]
```

Comment: Your code does not work in Command Line Tool project of Xcode 8.2.1. Seems some part of your code is **fragile**.

Comment: I ran it in playground in Xcode 8.2.1 and it runs ok there.

Comment: The Playground may allocate memory in a different way than actual apps, so your code may **accidentally** seem to work in the Playground.

Comment: Interesting! So, we should always test in Command Line Tool ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there may be other chances that the fragile code would work only in Command Line Tools. You need to be ultra-careful with unsafe-something and test the code in as much environment as you can. In this case, `xf` is too short for `vDSP_conv`, it needs to contain _at least `N + P - 1`_ elements.

Comment: Good to know OOPer. I am very new to Swift myself. So, learning everyday. I think, we can put an 'if statement' to check for count of xf.

Comment: In this case, you can supply enough elements with `xf = [Float](repeating:0.0, count:convN-N) + xf + [Float](repeating:0.0, count:convN-N)`. Always checking the length of the array may be a good habit, but sometimes very hard in practical code. Anyway, you'd better check the restriction noted in the doc of the function you want to use.

Comment: I was using swift 2.2.
But it was long time ago and swift has been through a significant major update.
I'll check how Accelerate works on newer version of swift to see whether this issue is still there or not.